# Chromium - ignore HSTS for specific domain

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

I support an ancient industrial HTTP-only web application that users access via `http://app.suborg.example.com/`. I recently discovered that a different site `https://example.com/` has set HSTS too aggressively, by adding `includeSubDomains`

Now if a user visits `example.com`, they will immediately be unable to access `app.suborg.example.com`, since the browser redirects to HTTPS. This results in a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` page, because the server doesn't listen for https. We can manually navigate to `about://net-internals/#hsts` and delete the entry every time, but it's not ideal.

So far, I've tried:

- Contacting the top-level site administrators: not going well
- Typing `thisisunsafe`: only works on certificate error pages, which I don't actually see
- Chrome Policy [HttpAllowlist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=HttpAllowlist): Specifically excludes HSTS upgrades, so no effect
- Chrome Policy [HSTSPolicyBypassList](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#HSTSPolicyBypassList): Only allows single-label hostnames, so no effect
- Adjusting the server to allow connections via a single-label name `http://app/`: it has hardcoded hostnames internally... it will respond, but usually 404 due to missing resources.

Does modern Chromium/Chrome/Edge have any options outside of deleting HSTS entries manually? There's not many users and I support them directly, so even a fiddly solution would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpAllowlist](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=HttpAllowlist) does not apply to HSTS upgrades. [HSTSPolicyBypassList](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#HSTSPolicyBypassList) does not prevent HSTS upgrades for servers that have "dynamically" requested HSTS upgrades using a Strict-Transport-Security response header. I think that's why they don't take effect.

I found a [useful blog](https://textslashplain.com/2022/05/16/unexpectedly-https/) and you can check the **Local Diagnostics** paragraph. For that `example.com` domain, if `FORCE_HTTPS` show in `dynamic_upgrade_mode`, the suggested fix "Clear Browsing Data > Cached images and files: All time" works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tested your suggestions today, and unfortunately neither actually work in this case. The description for `InsecureContentAllowedForUrls` implies that it only applies to site contents, like HTTP resources on HTTPS sites. I was surprised to find that even `AutomaticHttpsDefault=0` and Chrome's flag still result in https redirection when the HSTS policy is present. It is supposed to fall back to HTTP on failure though, so it's probably not being used here

Comment: I found a [useful blog](https://textslashplain.com/2022/05/16/unexpectedly-https/) and you can check the **Local Diagnostics** paragraph. For that `example.com` domain, does `FORCE_HTTPS` show in `static_upgrade_mode` or `dynamic_upgrade_mode`? It looks like your domain is accidentally HSTS pre-loaded into browsers’ preload list (forgetting that this will apply to subdomains), in this situation, you [don’t have great options](https://textslashplain.com/2018/04/09/hsts-preload-and-subdomains/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The domain is not preloaded, but does indeed show `dynamic_upgrade_mode: FORCE_HTTPS`, so the suggested fix "Clear Browsing Data > Cached images and files: All time" works, and is a bit simpler at least.